# How do I wrap a return type with a promise in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm writing Angular 1.x with TypeScript, and I have a service (DataService) that's responsible for loading data. For a simple example, it queries for a node and returns a node. In the interface:

```
getNode(id: number): ng.IPromise<Node>;
```

and the implementation:

```
  getNode(id: number) {
            return this.ajaxService.getNode(id)
                .then((result: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Node>) => {
                    return new Node(result.data.ID, result.data.Name);
                });
        }
```

However, I would like to introduce another service that stores these results and returns them if I've already queried for them before. So something like:

```
getNode(id: number) {
        var loadedNode = this.storageService.nodes.filter(e => (e.ID == id));
        if (loadedNode.length > 0) {
            return loadedNode[0];
        }

        return this.ajaxService.getNode(id)
            .then((result: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Node>) => {
                var n = new Node(result.data.ID, result.data.Name);
                this.storageService.nodes.push(n);
                return n;
            });
    }
```

However, the return type fails because it's expecting 'ng.IPromise' rather than just 'Node'. How can I wrap 'return loadedNode[0];' into some sort of promise return type rather than returning the actual object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the [`$q`-service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
getNode(id: number) {
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    var loadedNode = this.storageService.nodes.filter(e => (e.ID == id));
    if (loadedNode.length > 0) {
        // immediately resolve with the cached node
        deferred.resolve(loadedNode[0]);
    } else {
        // else load through service
        this.ajaxService.getNode(id)
            .then((result: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Node>) => {
                var n = new Node(result.data.ID, result.data.Name);
                this.storageService.nodes.push(n);

                // resolve with the loaded node
                deferred.resolve(n);
            });
    }

    // return the promise to register callbacks
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Usage:

```
myService.getNode(id).then((node) => {
    // success
}, () => {
    // error
});
```

Comment: Do I have to change the return type in the interface? At the moment, it's 

  getNode(id: number): ng.IPromise<Node>;

But TypeScript doesn't seem to pop up that it should know that the return type is a promise of a Node. 

This isn't causing any problems now, but I was trying to use this on another method

getChildren(id: number): ng.IPromise<Node[]>;

And TypeScript doesn't know the promised return type is an array

Comment: Solved my own problem by putting the return type on the method itself, not just on the interface.

Comment: Then it looks like you're using the class itself instead of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

use $q.when(value, [successCallback], [errorCallback], [progressCallback])

you can change the return line with

```
return $q.when(loadedNode[0]);
```

more info at [angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)